# Using Leaflet, PostGIS and pgRouting for web mapping

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, leaflet

I am new to Open Source GIS. I have already created a web mapping using custom tiles and Leaflet. I have used my own database. TileMill was used to create the tiles and Leaflet was used to visualize the tiles. Now I want to create a query of routing and Drive direction on the web mapping. I saw some tutorials of underdark in the following blog where routing visualization was done through QGIS software.

http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/pgrouting/

Now I want to know that whether it is possible to use my custom data (shape file) as PostGIS to visualize routing on web map or not?

Comment: This is a really confusing question. Can you explain what you already have in terms of input data, what you already have (perhaps a diagram of your architecture?) and exactly what functionality doesn't yet exist that you need?

Answer (score 3):

pgRouting and PostGIS dont't restrict you in how you display a route. Whether you use LEaflet, OpenLayers or QGIS, you always need to import your road network data into a PostgreSQL database, prepare it to be able to run the pgRouting shortest path function, etc.. 
And then you will have to write an application that for example accepts a start and end point as parameters and returns a route in a format that Leaflet for example can display.

Answer (score 1):

This youtube series goes through the process of acquiring network data for pgRouting, importing into Geoserver and building an application using leaflet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gfdQmFkVmE&list=PLaOYwKHOUv7Z2KyZNTXhLhwYm-XeEs34H

Comment: As links can break or videos be removed, please provide a small description of the process so that future users can use this answer even if the links breaks.

Answer (score 0):

pgRouting is the backend, you have to write the SQL queries to use for front-end,

Here is a Simple Backend Service for Pgrouting written in Node js Express.
to provide a route for front-end or mobile applications.

Setup config and use.

https://github.com/imran-5/pgRouting-Web-API